# RSA-SHA1 signature differs in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I need to create a `RSA-SHA1` signature in nodeJS, I am using the following code

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");
const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA1');
sign.update(data);
const result = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64')
console.log(result);
```

I'm double checked that my code result is true, I have same result with online tools if I select `sha1WithRSA` algorithm and I also get same result in PHP when I use `openssl_sign` function

I need to sign data for a bank API, Unfortunately they don't accept my signature and they have no NodeJS implementation

Also their documentation is a total mess, Here is the `C#` implementation of their document

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(“<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>oQRshGhLf2Fh...”);
string data = "DATA";
byte[] signMain = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
sign = Convert.ToBase64String(signMain);
```

Can someone help me to understand why my signature is not equal to the `C#` implementation (I don't check result of C# but their server written in C# and they don't verify my signature)

The following links to other official code fragments in PHP that together work with their server, but the result differs from standard `openssl_sign` function in PHP: [index L211-L216](https://github.com/ex7r3me/pasargad-woocommerce/blob/master/pasargad-woocommerce/index.php#L211-L216), [RSAProcessor L45](https://github.com/ex7r3me/pasargad-woocommerce/blob/master/pasargad-woocommerce/RSAProcessor.php#L45), [rsa.class L17-L22](https://github.com/ex7r3me/pasargad-woocommerce/blob/master/pasargad-woocommerce/rsa.class.php#L17-L22), [rsa.class L63-L82](https://github.com/ex7r3me/pasargad-woocommerce/blob/master/pasargad-woocommerce/rsa.class.php#L63-L82).

1. Is their implementation a non-standard RSA-SHA1?
2. What's wrong with my NodeJS code that their don't accept it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The posted NodeJS code and C# code generate the same signature for my test data. I would recommend you to post a complete example, i.e. a test message to be signed and a test key, as well as the signatures generated with both codes.

Comment: @Topaco thanks for your response, As I mentioned before, their documentation is a total mess, and I don't generate with C# code, but I tested with their PHP code, the sign result different, Please try the PHP version https://www.pep.co.ir/uploads/pep-phpsample(v3.3.3).rar it generate different sign

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have the time to create an MCVE for this PHP suite. You should do that so that a repro is available to test against your NodeJS code. Anyway, it would be strange (but of course possible) if the C# code of the bank API would be inconsistent with the PHP code of the bank API concerning the signature.

Comment: First, the obvious: (a) public key of verification matches private key used to sign? (b) data signed is exactly the same, including character encoding and size in byte? (c) encoding of signature is the same (if signature size differs by more than 1 or 2 bytes, this shows a different encoding). The reference code uses base-64 on the signature, the question does not! (d) RSA with SHA-1 can be RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (old but common) or RSASSA-PSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NodeJS code and the posted C# code provide the same signature for the same data to be signed and the same private key.

From the posted [link](https://github.com/ex7r3me/pasargad-woocommerce/blob/master/pasargad-woocommerce/index.php#L211) it can be seen that the SHA1 hashed data is passed to [`RSA::rsa_sign`](https://github.com/ex7r3me/pasargad-woocommerce/blob/master/pasargad-woocommerce/rsa.class.php#L17), but nowhere is the SHA1 digest ID prepended. Consistent with this is that no digest is specified in the function parameters either.

The padding itself takes place in [`RSA::add_PKCS1_padding`](https://github.com/ex7r3me/pasargad-woocommerce/blob/master/pasargad-woocommerce/rsa.class.php#L63). Here, for signing, RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 is applied. The passed (already hashed) data is processed, as said, without considering the digest ID.

Thus, the signature created by the PHP code is not compliant with [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2), while both the NodeJS code and the C# code follow the standard.

To my knowledge, when signing with the `sign` methods of the *crypto* module of *NodeJS*, a digest must always be specified and the digest ID is always set *implicitly*, so the signature of the PHP code cannot be reproduced with this.

An alternative that allows *not* to set the digest ID is [`crypto.privateEncrypt`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_privateencrypt_privatekey_buffer). The following code generates the signature of the PHP code or the signing process described in the posted [link](https://github.com/ex7r3me/pasargad-woocommerce/blob/master/pasargad-woocommerce/index.php#L211) if the same data and private key are used:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')

var sha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1')
sha1.update(data)
var hash = sha1.digest()

var signature = crypto.privateEncrypt({key: privateKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING}, hash) 
console.log(signature.toString('base64'))
```

Another question is whether this signature can be verified by the bank API. After all, the documentation of the API apparently contains two inconsistent implementations, so the documentation does not seem to be very reliable. Moreover, other flaws are of course possible, see the comment by fgrieu.

Comment: thanks for your response, Can you please tell me more about digest ID and can you show me equivalent of `sign` using `privateEncrypt`, just for my educational purpose

Comment: _RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5_ is explained in detail in [_RFC 8017_, sec. 8.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-8.2). This is a padding used in the context of signing. The ID of the digest applied is placed before the hashed data, e.g. for SHA1 this is _0x3021300906052b0e03021a05000414_, [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#page-47). If the digest ID is considered in the `privateEncrypt` call: `Buffer.concat([Buffer.from("3021300906052b0e03021a05000414", "hex"), hash])`, the signature of the `sign` call is reproduced.